# How to convert this for loop into recursion? Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, recursion

I have got this code which basically searches through a string in search for a letter (because I have to make sure there are no letters). If there is no letter in the string, string is valid, if there is a letter then the string. I got this for loop but I need to convert it into a recursive form using a function:

```
dim valid as boolean = true
For i = 0 To string.Length() - 1
        If IsNumeric(string(i)) = False Then
            valid = False
        End If
Next
```

Where valid is a flag

Thanks

Comment: I don't know  visual basic  syntax, but what you want to do is call a function with parameter  String.length() -1, the function returns true if parameter is 0 and false if the character at parameter isn't numeric. otherwise it calls the function with parameter -1.

Comment: So how would that translate to psudeocode code?
(Sorry I'm just struggling to follow what you wrote)

Comment: Microsoft guidelines/example here: [Recursive Procedures - Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/recursive-procedures
).